# CLion: permanent language injections based on raw string literal?

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, clion

Given a raw string literal like:

```
const string& myproto = R"prototext(
    notification_target: FOO
    notification_type: 99
prototext)prototext";
```

Can I configure CLion to always inject the `prototext` lang into raw strings beginning with "prototext"?

I know I can do it temporarily via the lightbulb:

[image]

But I can't figure out how to do it via the settings:

[image]

I think PhpStorm/WebStorm can do it for JS tagged template strings, so I don't see why we can't do it for C++ raw strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's not possible. Feel free to create a feature request in CLion's tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP.